# How to avoid page break on refreshing page using react-router-dom with a private route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having an issue with React Router route. When I click on the component, it takes me to the correct Route and renders the correct component. However, whenever I refresh the page, it breaks and nothing shows up on the page

### index.js (container)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import RouteWithSubRoutes from '../../utils/Auth/RouteWithSubRoutes';
import routes from '../../routes';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(route => (
          <RouteWithSubRoutes
            key={route.path}
            {...route}
            routes={route.routes}
          />
        ))}
      </Switch>
      <GlobalStyle />
    </div>
  );
}
App.propTypes = {
};
```

### RouteWithSubRoutes.js (Components)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
class RouteWithSubRoutes extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const route = this.props;
    return (
      <Route
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        render={props => {
          if (!route.auth){
            return (
            <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
            );
          }else{
            return (
              <PrivateRoute {...props} component={route.component} routes={route.routes} />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default RouteWithSubRoutes;
```

### PrivateRoute.js (Components)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { DAEMON } from '../constants';
import { makeSelectLoginStatus } from '../../containers/Login/selectors';
import saga from '../../containers/Login/saga';
import injectSaga from '../injectSaga';
import routesss from '../../../app/routes';
class PrivateRoute extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, routes, authSuccess, ...rest } = this.props;
]    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          authSuccess ? (
            <Component {...props} routes={routes} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/admin/login',
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'login', saga, mode: DAEMON });
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  authSuccess: makeSelectLoginStatus(),
});
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps);
export default compose(
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(PrivateRoute);
```

However, when I refresh the page after the component has been rendered, the page breaks and nothing pops up. I don't get any error in the console.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are propably using BrowserRouter from react-router and your backend fails to serve resource on requested route after refresh?

Comment: i'm not using BrowserRouter , am using PrivateRoute with auth. @Pavel Kratochvil

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start if  App in index.js is root component then you didnt define Router in your component structure. For testing purposes use hashRouter and lemme know.